# Infragistics ig.WebCapture Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, infragistics

```
$('#btnTest').click(function () {
    var captcha = $IG.WebCaptcha.find('capWebCaptcha');

    alert(captcha.get_validationFailed());

    // alert($IG.WebCaptcha);
});
```

This is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $IG.WebCaptcha.find is not a function

I found the example from the URL below:
http://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/webcaptcha_captcha_validation.html

I am following all the instructions as provided.  Has anybody seen this before or can somebody offer a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get reference using  var captcha = ig_controls.capWebCaptcha, where the Id may differ if teh control is placed in panel, loaded from user control, etc.